# Unity: Raycast Doesn't Work For The Child Object's Collider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a tile based game. I place towers as child objects of tiles. I want to be able to detect mouse clicks on towers but not tiles, with raycasting. Both tiles and the towers have 2d box colliders. I can detect clicks on tiles but raycast won't detect the ones on the towers. How can I solve this problem. Thanks.

Here is my code for raycasting:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

            ray.origin = camera.transform.position;

            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(camera.transform.position, -Vector2.up, 50, 8);

            if (hit.collider != null && !EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
            {
                Debug.Log(hit.collider.transform.tag);
                //Transform objectHit = hit.transform;

            }
        }
    }
```

When I mask the tiles (here layer 8) I get nothing. It seems rays never hit the towers although towers (like tiles) also have a 2d box collider.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the properties of the problematic collider? Is the raycast hitting anything at all? More details will help narrow the problem down to an answerable state.

Comment: You can check with collider of  tiles and find if tiles have child then control it... [https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.GetChild.html](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.GetChild.html)

Comment: Please ask the actual question. Try to describe issue as good as its possible

Comment: I edited the question. Can you have a look at it now? @Serlite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little research it seems that all child colliders of an object are considered to belong to the parent. This is so that you can build up a more complex collider out of smaller ones and this situation is commonly needed. The exact collider can still be referenced using it's transform property, for example:

```
if (hit.collider.transform != null)
{
   //Execute code
}
```

This will refer to the childs collider specifically.

Comment: This works perfect.Just one more question. When I'm casting the ray at the mouse position I get null reference error when mouse is outside the game view. at the line * if (hit.collider.transform != null) *. Why does this happen while I'm actually checking if it is null?

Comment: Ah well this checks the property of an object that we may not necessarily have. So first check if the object is null then check if the property of the object is null (check hit.collider then also check hit.collider.transform). You can do this in the same if statement as long as the highest in the hierarchy is checked first.

Comment: I hope that makes sense but will reword it if not.

Comment: Thank you sir! You helped me out in solving the major problem in my project!

Comment: Not a problem, I'm very glad to hear you got it working ok! Hope the rest of the project goes well.

Answer (score 1):

Unity uses a layer system and you can filter out which layers raycasts are using. You can use this to hit specific colliders and avoid others like your tiles/ towers issue. The syntax (for 2d version) is:

```
RaycastHit2D Raycast(Vector2 origin, Vector2 direction, float distance
= Mathf.Infinity, int layerMask = DefaultRaycastLayers, float minDepth
= -Mathf.Infinity, float maxDepth = Mathf.Infinity);
```

Here you can see the layermask parameter choose a different layer to the one your parent object is on. Then place the children on a different layer using the drop down menu in the inspector as seen below.

[image]

You can set the layers of parents and child gameobjects separately.

Hope that helps

Comment: This would solve it but if you can post some code however the community can help eliminate your specific issue.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question sorry for not providing the code before I was too tired. The thing is, I place towers as childs of tiles, but the ray never hits the towers. When I mask tiles, I get nothing.

Comment: can you check it out now? @Mr.Bigglesworth

Comment: I have made some edits to my answer, just want to make sure you are setting the layers of the tiles and towers in the inspector and they are different.

Comment: That's great news @Halil Karagöz! Did my answer help or was it something else?

Comment: I actually solved the problem checking if the parent object has a child. Apparently, ray only hits the parent's collider. The code takes the appropriate action if the parent object has a specific type of child(using tags). It seems It doesn't have to do anything to do with layers in my case. But ray not hitting the child object's collider is my idea. What do you think about it? @Mr.Bigglesworth

Comment: @HalilKaragöz Interesting stuff going on around these colliders, I have learned something new. I added an alternative answer I hope will help others with your situation. Thank you